# Facebook Banner Ads not displaying properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, facebook

Banner Ads not displaying properly it display half i can't find out what is the problem. if anybody know please help me.

i am using POD and Manually add Facebook audience network. but the result are same.

is this SDK Bug?

[image]

I am using this code

```
@Property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *adContainer;
@Property (nonatomic, strong) FBAdView *adView;

(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.adView = [[FBAdView alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID"
adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner
rootViewController:self];
self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
self.adView.delegate = self;
[self.adView loadAd];
}

(void)adViewDidLoad:(FBAdView *)adView
{
NSLog(@"Ad was loaded and ready to be displayed");
[self showBanner];
}

(void)showBanner
{
if (self.adView && self.adView.isAdValid) {
[self.adContainer addSubview:self.adView];
}
}
```

- I am use pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
  And Manual
- Download iOS Audience Network SDK 6.0.0
- iOS Audience Network SDK 5.10.1
- and Add FBSDKCoreKit

I am check every thing one by one but not work properly. same issue in all this.
Please help :)

Comment: I think you need to change the frame, maybe change the 50 height in the frame to 100 and see how it goes.

Comment: @skaak no bro frame is not problem because i am directly add in self.view also

Comment: Are you sure? Adding it won't change the frame? If that is not the issue I'm not sure myself ... not really using FB adds ... just eyeballed the code ...